# Installing bundler within Jenkins Docker image

Tags: ruby, bash, jenkins, docker

Is it possible to install Ruby within a docker image, specifically Jenkins?

I can see from the docs that you can attach to a container or use `docker exec -i -t 4e2bf4128e3e bash`. This will log me in as `jenkins@4e2bf4128e3e`.

But if I try and install anything

```
apt-get install ruby 2.0.0 # Yes will install rvm, this is just an example
```

I get

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

And when I try

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 2.0.0
```

Then I get `sudo command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that, as you can see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/373c45a59fbaa2b15e77408425205b158352480e/Dockerfile#L58), the jenkins docker images executes commands as the jenkins user which is forbidden to use apt.

On https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/ you have some documentation, namely the "Installing more tools" section which advise you to do this:

```
FROM jenkins
# if we want to install via apt
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby make more-thing-here
USER jenkins # drop back to the regular jenkins user - good practice
```

Comment: apologies, did not see this, so i have tried what you suggested and installed ruby and bundler as the root user. When running a build in jenkins the bundle command is not found?

Comment: How did you installed bundler ?

Comment: `RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc"` as the root user

Comment: There is an existing debian / ubuntu package for bundler. The problem here is that , gem installs binaries in GEM_PATH , but GEM_PATH is not in PATH. Next, you will install some gems with bundler, and when executing it won't take the gems nor binaries installed with gems, you will need to execute `bundle exec` before the command you want to run.

Comment: thats what I'm doing `bundle exec rubocop` for example

Comment: so i guess i need to add `GEM_PATH` to `PATH`, can't use bundle at all at the moment as the jenkins user

Comment: This is why i advised you to install bundler from the debian package (this one is in $PATH) rather than with `gem install bundler` (adding $GEM_PATH/bin or sth like that , would also work)

Comment: do you have a link to the debian package please ?

Comment: all packages named bundler in all distributions : https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bundler , Jessie's (stable) one : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/bundler, and the list of files of this package : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/bundler/filelist where you can see this package adds 3 binaries in path: `bundle` , `bundle_ruby` and `bundler`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112323/discussion-between-richlewis-and-user801247).

Comment: ok excuse me for coming across as thick, but how would you set your dockerfile up then to achieve the setup i require?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own image, that layers those two images

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins
FROM ruby
...
```

Now you have a docker container of your own that has both ruby AND jenkins.

Comment: This method doesn't always works. It works here because both ruby and jenkins images are based on debian jessie. Also, I think that if some files (above the debian layers) are present in both images, then, the resulting build will end up with files from the ruby image.

Comment: This method should not be used, a Dockerfile should not have multiple `FROM`s, see this answer for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/37295842/768635

Comment: I think i'd rather trust the official [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) over some StackOverflow post from the community.  `"FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile in order to create multiple images. Simply make a note of the last image ID output by the commit before each new FROM command."`

Comment: if this is possible how do i note the last image id ? this is my current issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295433/run-docker-after-building-own-image thanks