# Run docker after building own image

Tags: jenkins, docker

After a previous post it was suggested to create my own Docker image, I wanted to have jenkins with ruby, so my dockerfile looks like

```
FROM jenkins
FROM ruby:2.3.0
```

I run `docker build -t jenkins_ruby .`

It builds correctly and i can see the image when i do `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jenkins             latest              77bd697ef2c3        5 days ago          710.1 MB
jenkins_ruby        latest              1653f4c3a826        8 days ago          729 MB
ruby                latest              1653f4c3a826        8 days ago          729 MB
```

So i then want to run this image in a container `docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins_ruby`

but i get `Switch to inspect mode.`

I was expecting to be able to go to `ipaddress:8080` and see the jenkins console

Have i missed something?

Thanks

Comment: I added an answered yesterday on your first question explaining why you shouldn't do 2 FROM, with a specific solution for your jenkins problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283809/installing-bundler-within-jenkins-docker-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dockerfile cannot have multiple `FROM`s.

This type of functionality to essentially merge two images together cannot be done in a single Dockerfile. All that's really happening here is that it will pull the `jenkins:latest` image, pull the `ruby:2.3.0` image and then tag the `ruby` image with `jenkins_ruby`. There is no merging occurring, you can see that with the image final sizes too, `jenkins_ruby` has an identical size to `ruby`.

There's a Github issue to back this up [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13026#issuecomment-210842623).